# Using Sinch with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, sinch

I'm targetting iOS and Android platforms for a messaging application.

I want to use voice and messaging features of the sdk.

Are there any bindings available for sinch sdk for xamarin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinch has a C# wrapper for sending SMS via their REST interface. It is available via a Nuget (Sinch.SMS) and/or you can grab the code on Github; https://github.com/sinch/Sinch.SMS

i.e. (from their hello world example):

To send an SMS use:

```
var client = new Sinch.SMS.Client("yourkey", "yoursecret");
var messageid = await client.SendSMS("+46722223355", "hello from sinch");
```

To check a status of an SMS use:

```
var client = new Sinch.SMS.Client("yourkey", "yoursecret");
var result = await client.CheckStatus(messageid);
```

As far as a complete SDK bindings for their Android/iOS SDKs, I do not know of one personally.

I 'just' would import them into XStudio and convert their sample call apps and give it a try. Should not take very long to see if the auto-wrappers work. Otherwise you would have manually correct/write the C# bindings to their 'native' lib

Comment: We also released a Verification c# wrapper yesterday https://github.com/sinch/nuget-sinch.verification

Answer (score 2):

Here are some Xamarin binding libraries available on nuget. They are by a Vietnamese Software Development company called NAXAM. I believe these are all open source, and published on their github here: https://github.com/NAXAM

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.SinchVoice.Droid/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.SinchVoice.iOS/3.11.0-pre1

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.SinchVerification.Droid/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.SinchVerification.iOS/2.0.4-pre1